# sprite-factory script not working in hook

Tags: codekit

I want to use sprite-factory to create sprites when saving .sass files in Codekit. I've added the following script as a Hook:

```
sf [full-path-to-WP-files]/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/images/icons
```

But it's not running.

What I know so far:

1. It works fine when run from terminal.
2. The hook is activated correctly (I put a touch filename.txt afterwards to test)
3. Changing the path to be relative to the Codekit config file didn't help.

Does anyone know why it's not working, and what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks!

**Addition**

`sf` is working fine when run from the dir containing config.codekit in terminal

Answer (score 0):

where is the `sf` utility installed? Dump the `PATH` environment variable at the start of your Hook and make sure that it contains the folder where `sf` is installed:

```
echo $PATH | logger
```

Then use Console.app to inspect the output.

Comment: Thanks, where is the log file?

Comment: View it with Console.app.

Comment: My question was which file to view in Console.app, I added the line you suggested but don't see the output anywhere.